# when do we need a selector with jquery on click

Tags: jquery

Hi Editor: this is not a question about: .on('click') vs .click

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="someID">
        <a href="#">click</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery was working, not sure why not working now

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function(){ alert(8); });
```

It took me a while to figure out the following is now working, but still not sure why:

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'a', function(){ alert(8); });
```

Comment: are the elements dynamically created?

Comment: It is dynamically added

Comment: Hi Tushar - could you remove the duplicate tag on above?